# Add query to form action using PHP or JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, action

I'm using Gravity form on my Wordpress site, Gravity form generate automatic form action, I was wondering if i can add a query at the end of each action.

This is default code which is generated

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'  id='gform_4'  action='/free-trial/'>
```

And i want to be like

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'  id='gform_4'  action='/free-trial/#testdiv'>
```

I searched and found lots of jquery or php code which was over my head, i just need a simple code.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `$('#gform_4').attr('action', function(a) { return a + '#testdiv' });`

Comment: And you used the wordpress way of including jQuery etc -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: oops, no sorry, works now, one more thing, I have 6 form in my site and each form has different id, is there any way to detect all of them instead of defining specific ID?

Comment: Also, a "0" appears before the #testdiv
it looks like : free-trial/0#testdiv

Comment: You can use a class to target multiple elements. I have no idea where the zero is coming from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try getting the current form action value first, append the desired hash query then set the new value to the action attribute:

```
var url = $('#gform_4').attr('action') + '#testdiv';
$('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', url);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/C2mvG/)